# Enabling multiple textboxes with a corresponding multiple checkbox using a single jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, disabled-input

I have 4 multiple check boxes which each one of them is specifically correspondent to 4 text-boxes. I need to enable the disabled texbox when the corresponding checkbox is checked. I wrote a same function for each checkbox's onclick event in html tag itself as `onclick="document.getElementById('txtLrgPrc').disabled=!this.checked;"` .

But I need to automate this by calling a function only once by sending the parameters of textboxes and heckboxes(i.e. id or name,,) to my js file using jQuery. Can anyone help me for refining this please?

Here is the code which I am currently using and it works finely.

jsp page:

```
<div class="row item-tbl-row" id="addItmChkbxReg">

                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <form:checkbox value="regular" class="checkbox sizechkbx" path="size" label="Regular" id="chkReg" onclick="document.getElementById('txtRegPrc').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control price" path="price" id="txtRegPrc" disabled="true"/>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row item-tbl-row" id="addItmChkbxMed">

                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <form:checkbox value="medium" class="checkbox sizechkbx" path="size" label="Medium" onclick="document.getElementById('txtMedPrc').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control price" path="price" id="txtMedPrc" disabled="true"/>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row item-tbl-row" id="addItmChkbxLrg">

                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <form:checkbox value="large" class="checkbox sizechkbx" path="size" label="Large" onclick="document.getElementById('txtLrgPrc').disabled=!this.checked;"/>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control price" path="price" id="txtLrgPrc" disabled="true"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Start by adding a jQuery `click` event handler that references the class common to your checkboxes ("col-xs-5").  If you have trouble making it work, then post back with questions.  (Make sure you understand how `event.target` and `this` work inside an event handler.  This is standard reading.)

Comment: @BobRodes This is what I tried so far

`$(function enableTextbox(chk, txt){

        //option 1
        if(chk.checked == true)
            txt.disable(false);

        
        //option 2
        if(chk.is(':checked')) {
            $(txt).find(txt).attr('disabled', false);

        }

    })`


in jsp;


`<form:checkbox value="regular" class="checkbox sizechkbx" path="size" label="Regular" id="chkReg" onclick="enableTextbox(this,'txtRegPrc')"/>`


What am I messing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".checkbox").click(function () {

            $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".form-control").prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, remove the click event of the checkboxes.

**Another solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function C(t, textBoxId) {
        $("#" + textBoxId).prop("disabled", !$(t).prop("checked"));
    }
</script>

<form:checkbox value="regular" id="chkReg" onclick="C(this, 'txtRegPrc')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks , it works . But I am trying to do this via sending parameters like id of the text box when calling the relevant function onclick event of checkbox. Because I need to understand jQuery functions how handling these things via sending parameters

Comment: I tried several codes same like the second solution of yours. But they didn't work. Also  I tried your 2nd solution but it didn't work either. Will it be the problem that I am calling the function from a jsp page in a separate js file ?